# Does a Paypal user Pay tax for receiving payment in uk

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, paypal, payment

I'm trying to set up a PayPal account for my company (that is not registered in the UK) and want to use my UK account to receive payment on the website.

Does anyone know if I will be taxed for receiving payment in my UK account?

Comment: Warning: check the paypal rules for this, they may not want you using a personal account for business transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You won’t be taxed just for receiving money into your account, but if you’re liable for tax in the UK, HMRC will have access to your PayPal account and may expect you to account for the money when filling in your tax return.

Comment: Is it possible witholding tax could be due upon removing the money to a non-tax-treaty destination country?